# onsubmit="return checkform(this);" seems to be empty for my form

Tags: php, javascript, html

When I click Submit, I get an error that the value is undefined in my javascript that I use to validate my form for the aForm.propertyid.

I'm thinking this is related to using a select and trying to verify a value was chosen, as I've not validated against a select before and my other forms all work fine.

The correct values are in the $_POST in lease_edita, but the checkForm(this) doesn't seem to pass anything to the javascript for validation - my checkForm(aValue) didn't get aValue.

I added an alert in my checkForm to display the value for error checking, and it's not getting a value.  The onchange="checkProperty(this.value);" works correctly though and does get a value.

propertyid is undefined @/lease_jsLibrary.js

I'm hoping I'm posting enough code... I've been working on this for 2 days without finding a fix, and am hopeful for suggestions or ideas.

The form:

```
<form name ="addEditLeaseForm" id="addEditLeaseForm" action="lease_edita.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
<?php
$output = <<<HTML
    <table class="center1" width="500">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right; ">
            Property:
            </td>
            <td>
            <select name="propertyid" id="propertyid" stle="width:270px;" onchange="checkProperty(this.value);" />
                <option value='' selected></option>
HTML;
                $propList = getPropertyList();  // get the properties to populate the list box
                foreach ($propList as $aProperty) {
                extract($aProperty);
                $output .= <<<HTML
                <option value="$idproperty"
HTML;
                if ($idproperty == $prop_id) {
                $output .= <<<HTML
 selected
HTML;
            }
                $output .= <<<HTML
>$address</option>
HTML;
            }
                $output .= <<< HTML
            </select>
            <font id="propertyErr" style="visibility: hidden; color:red; font-weight: bold;">*Required</font>

            </td>
        </tr>
HTML;
    echo $output;
?>
    <tr>
    <td colspan ="2" align="center">
         <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $buttontext ?>" />
        <input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
</form>

<p style="text-align: center">
    <input type="button" name="Property" value="Back to Property" onclick="window.location = '../property/property_main.php' " />
</p>
```

lease_jsLibrary.js contents:

```
function trim(strToTrim) {
    "use strict";
    //create a regular expression literal to identify leading and trailing spaces
    var reg = /^\s+|\s+$/g;
    //use the string method - replace - to remove leading and trailing spaces
    return strToTrim.replace(reg,"");
}

// checks whether an input control is empty (i.e., the user failed to enter a required input)
// note: it uses the trim method (see above) to eliminate white spaces before checking the input
function isEmpty(aControl) {
    return (trim(aControl.value).length == 0) ? true : false;
}

// checks for invalid characters in a string
function hasInvalidChars(aControl) {
    //create a regular expression literal to identify invalid characters
    var reg = /[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\&\!\?\.',_-]/;
    //use the regular expression method - test - to check whether the string contains invalid characters
    return reg.test(trim(aControl.value));
}

// removes starting and trailing white spaces
function trimBlur(strToTrim) {
    "use strict";
    //create a regular expression literal to identify leading and trailing spaces
    var reg = /^\s+|\s+$/g;
    //use the string method - replace - to remove leading and trailing spaces
    return strToTrim.replace(reg, "");
}

// checks whether an input control is empty (i.e., the user failed to enter a required input)
// note: it uses the trim method (see above) to eliminate white spaces before checking the input
function isEmptyBlur(aControl) {
    "use strict";
    return (trimBlur(aControl).length === 0) ? true : false;
}

function checkProperty(aValue) {
    "use strict";
alert(aValue);
    if (isEmptyBlur(aValue)) {
    document.getElementById("propertyErr").style.visibility='visible';
    document.getElementById("propertyid").style.borderColor='#FF3300';
    document.getElementById("propertyErr").innerHTML="*Required";
    return false;
    } else {
    document.getElementById("propertyErr").style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById("propertyid").style.borderColor='';
    return true;
    }
}

function checkForm(aValue) {
    alert (aValue.propertyid);
    if (isEmpty(aValue.propertyid)) {
    document.getElementById("propertyErr").style.visibility='visible';
    document.getElementById("propertyid").style.borderColor='#FF3300';
    document.getElementById("propertyErr").innerHTML="*Required";
    return false;
    } else return true;
}
```

thanks in advance for tips, suggestions, and ideas..

this is fixed by changing to use:
    if (isEmpty(aValue.propertyid.value))
thank you!!!

Comment: Are you supposed to be checking `aValue.propertyid` instead of `aForm.propertyid`? `aValue` doesn't appear to be defined anywhere.

Comment: nitpicks: `font` tags are deprecated, do not use them, it is not the 1990's. Use spans with css classes. Seeing `document.getElementById("propertyErr")` many times in a row is bad. Store it into a variable and use it. `var elem = document.getElementById("propertyErr"); elem.style.visibility = 'visible';`

Comment: Ahh, I see that..I changed that so that they it is all aValue in the checkForm(aValue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to check the `<select>` tag named "propertyid" ?

```
function checkForm(aForm) {
    if ( !aForm.propertyid.value  ) { // so replace the line with this
        document.getElementById("propertyErr").style.visibility='visible';
        document.getElementById("propertyid").style.borderColor='#FF3300';
        document.getElementById("propertyErr").innerHTML="*Required";
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log( "submited" );
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not just slap on `innerHTML` when `textContent()`/`innerText` should be used .. and instead of macing about with style attributes ( which **each** time triggers [*Reflow*](http://www.bitcurrent.com/browser-rendering-and-web-performance-reflow/) in the browser ) , you should add a class

Comment: Thanks!  added this and it worked great... I need a better second set of eyes.

Comment: Also: Just found [JavaScript: Form Validation][1] that also explains this well.  thank you again for you help, and I'll work on implementing the other comments and feedback, I don't want to be in the 1990's :(


  [1]: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate/